# How do I factorize this numerator?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to -3}   \frac 1{x+3} + \frac 4{x^2+2x-3}$$

I have the solution I just need to know how i turn that into:
$$\frac {(x-1)+4}{(x+3)(x-1)}$$

I know this might be really simple but I'm not sure how to factorise the numerator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: I edited and formatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to ensure that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: No it's perfect, thank you!

Comment: $ x^2+2x-3 = (x+3)(x-1)$ and common denominator?

Comment: It's just the sum. Of course, the easy way is observing that $x^2+2x-3$ is a multipe of $x+3$.

Comment: Yes I understand that, just wondering how you get (x-1)+4

Comment: @Sv7 Sum the two fractions.

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean by Sum the fractions?

Comment: $ \dfrac 1{x+3} + \dfrac 4{x^2+2x-3} =  \dfrac {x-1}{(x+3)(x-1)} + \dfrac 4{(x+3)(x-1)} =  \dfrac {(x-1)-4}{(x+3)(x-1)} $

Answer (score 3):

You have to factorise the second fraction:
$$\frac{4}{(x+3)(x-1)}$$

Then the first fraction can be made into:
$$\frac{1}{x+3}\times\frac{x-1}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1)}{(x+3)(x-1)}$$
Now you have this, you can add fractions like normal, as the two fractions have the same denominator:
$$\frac{4}{(x+3)(x-1)}+\frac{(x-1)}{(x+3)(x-1)} = \frac{(x-1)+4}{(x+3)(x-1)}$$

You can simplify that to:
$$\frac{(x+3)}{(x+3)(x-1)}$$
And simplify again to:
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)}$$
Because x tends to -3, you could simply write it as:
$$-\frac{1}{4}$$
Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes it did, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$ x^2+2x-3 = (x-1)(x+3),$$

so

$$\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{4}{x^2+2x-3}=\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{4}{(x-1)(x+3)}=\frac{1(x-1) +4}{(x-1)(x+3)} $$

Comment: I am a bit confused to where the (x-1) on the numerator comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [common denominator](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/common-denominator.html) technique:

$$
\frac 1{x+3} + \frac 4{x^2+2x-3} = \frac {1}{x+3} + \frac {4}{(x+3)(x-1)} =  \frac {1 \times (x-1) + 4 \times 1}{(x+3)(x-1)} = \frac{x-1+4}{(x+3)(x-1)}
$$

Take a denominator which divisible to both denominators as the common denominator and divide that by each denominator separately, then multiply its quotient by its numerator.

Answer (score 1):

First off note that $$x^2 + 2x -3  = (x+3)(x-1)$$ We can therefore rewrite your equation as $$\lim_{x \to -3} \frac 1{x+3} + \frac 4{(x+3)(x-1)} \\ \lim_{x \to -3} \frac {(x-1)}{(x+3)(x-1)} + \frac 4{(x+3)(x-1)} \\ \lim_{x \to -3} \frac {x-1 + 4}{(x+3)(x-1)} \\ \lim_{x \to -3} \frac {x+3}{(x+3)(x-1)} \\ \lim_{x \to -3} \frac {1}{x-1} \\ -\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the left hand term, and multiply both the numerator and denominator by $(x-1)$. Then both terms will have the same denominator (factor the denominator of the right-hand term), and the numerator of the left-hand term will be $(x-1)$ as required.

This is allowed since multiplying both the numerator and denominator by the same (non-zero) value is equivalent to multiplying by 1, which obviously does not change the value.